# Sending two models with one controller

Tags: model, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I haven't been able to fit the logic in the MVC structure yet. My problem is:

```
public IActionResult Index(string ilceler)
        {
          
            var ETList = c.ETs.Where(p => p.Ilce == ilceler && p.ETDurumu != "YOK").OrderBy(p=>p.KurumAdi).ToList();
            var ETListOlmayanlar = c.ETs.Where(p => p.Ilce == ilceler &&p.ETDurumu=="YOK").OrderBy(p => p.KurumAdi).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

does not return  two models and are not bind on the view side.

Learn asp.net core details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DTO model that contains the two models you want.

I noticed that you are actually using the same model, but filtering the value of `ETDurumu` to create two sets of data. You can refer to my test code below:

Original model:

```
public class ETList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ilce { get; set; }
    public string ETDurumu { get; set; }
    public int KurumAdi { get; set; }
}
```

DTO model:

```
public class ETDTO
{
    public List<ETList> eTLists1 { get; set; }
    public List<ETList> eTLists2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string ilceler)
{
    ilceler = "test1";
    ETDTO eTDTO = new ETDTO();
    var ETList = c.ETs.Where(p => p.Ilce == ilceler && p.ETDurumu != "YOK").OrderBy(p => p.KurumAdi).ToList();
    var ETListOlmayanlar = c.ETs.Where(p => p.Ilce == ilceler && p.ETDurumu == "YOK").OrderBy(p => p.KurumAdi).ToList();
    eTDTO.eTLists1 = ETList;
    eTDTO.eTLists2 = ETListOlmayanlar;

    return View(eTDTO);
}
```

View(Use the DTO model):

```
@model Project.Models.ETDTO

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Ilce</th>
                <th>ETDurumu</th>
                <th>KurumAdi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model.eTLists1)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Ilce</td>
                    <td>@item.ETDurumu</td>
                    <td>@item.KurumAdi</td>
                </tr>    
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Ilce</th>
                <th>ETDurumu</th>
                <th>KurumAdi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.eTLists2)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Ilce</td>
                    <td>@item.ETDurumu</td>
                    <td>@item.KurumAdi</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Please let me know if this is what you want. Hope this can help you.

Comment: What's on my mind is this: Entities already has this model structure. Do I need to create a MODEL for every data I will use?

The model used to map data to the entity and the model used to return data to the UI ?

Comment: You can choose to create a model for just a few of these columns if you're only using them, but you'll need to do the mapping. The easiest way is of course to take out all the data and only load the few columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a view model that contain 2 model you want to use in that controller like:

```
class model1{...}
class modle2{...}
class view model 
{
   public model1 first model {get;set;}
   public model2 second model {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Then, instead of using all the table equivalents in entities, we will use only the columns that are needed with the viewmodel. This time we will have many viewmodels. Is this usage normal?

Comment: okay you can use DTO models structure and use mappers to convert them to each other and I think this is better in long time distance but the structure is not simple as view model but both of them is good
At last it's depend on your project and purpose